# Prove or disprove statements about running times

Tags: algorithm, computer-science, time-complexity

I'm working through chapter 3 of CLRS, which is about running times and would like to work through some examples. Since I'm not enrolled in an algorithms class I need to resort to the www for help.

1) n^2 = Big-Omega(n^3)

> I think this statement is false: if the best case running time is n^3, then the algorithm cannot be n^2, . Even the best case is slower than that.

2) n + log n = Big-Theta (n)

> I think this statement is true, we can ignore the lower term of log n. This gives us a worst-case running time of Big-Oh (n). And a best case running time of Big-Omega (n). I'm not quite sure of this though. Some more clarification would be appreciated.

3) n^2 log n =Big-Oh (n^2)

> I think this.statement is false: the worst case running time should be n^2 log n.

4) n log n = Big-Oh (n sqrt (n))

> Could be true since n log n < n sqrt (n). Not quite sure though.

5) n^2 - 3n - 18 = Big-Theta (n^2)
Really no idea...

6) If f (n) = O (g (n)) and g (n)  = O (h (n)), then f (n) = O (h (n)).

> Holds by the transitive property.

I hope someone Could elaborate a bit on my quite.possibly wrong answers :)

Comment: You have some fundamental misunderstanding about the notations. **(1)** `O(n^2)` (for example) is a *set*, while `n^2*log(n)` is a *function*. A function cannot be a set, it can be CONTAINED IN a set. The correct terminology will be `is n^2 * log(n)  in the set O(n^2)?`. **(2)** "best case/worst case" has nothing to do with the big O notation. Quick sort for example is `Theta(nlogn)` average case and `Theta(n^2)` worst case. The big O notation can be applied for each analyzes, since it is "grouping" the function provided by this analyzes.

Comment: @amit the `=` is often used with the `O()` notation.

Comment: Yeah, in the literature they use the '=' sign in stead of the 'is in set' symbol. Lets not disgress too much about this.

Comment: @JanDvorak: "often used" != correct. I have never seen a formal definition of the `=` for these cases. Of course - it doesn't mean one does not exist.

Comment: @amit this is a common practice and perfectly acceptable when calculating complexities. In this context `=` means `belongs to the set`, **unlike** the usual mathematical meaning of `=`.

Comment: `O(x)` means "asymptotically x or faster". `Theta(x)` means "asymtotically x". `OMEGA(x)` means "asymptotically x or slower".

Comment: @amit The notation even gets a special mentio in Knuth's Discrete Mathematics IIRC, but you're correct of course.

Comment: Not so often, but f(n) \in O(g(n)) is being used in & out of the literature. it is something everyone agrees on but nobody is willing to disturb the "tradition"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. You are correct, but the reason is not. Remember that Omega(n^3) does not directly relate to an algorithm—but to a function.
   The reason why you are correct is because: for each constant `c,N`, there is some `n>N` such that `n^2 < c * n^3`—and thus `n^2` is **not** in `Omega(n^3)`
2. You are correct.  `n < n + logn < 2*n` (for large enough n), and thus `n + logn` is both `O(n)` and `Omega(n)`
3. You are correct, but again, do not use "worst case" in here. The explanation and proof guidelines will be similar to *1.*
4. This is correct since `log(n)` is asymptotically smaller than `sqrt(n)` and the rest follows.
5. Same principle as in *1.* It will be true with the same approach.
6. Correct.

---

As a side note: `Omega(n)` does not mean "best case run time of `n`" it means that the *function* denoting the complexity (can be worst case complexity, best case complexity or average case complexity,...) holds the conditions for being `Omega(n)`.

For example - Quicksort:

- Under the worst case analysis , it is `Theta(n^2)`
- Whereas under the average case analysis it is `Theta(nlogn)`

Comment: I was tempted to downvote just to make your rep _exactly_ 40K. But I decided to vote based on the quality of the answer instead.

Comment: Thank you for this, @amit, it is clear I need to pay more attention to being as formal as possible. My understanding is a bit too 'loose' at the moment.